# When adding a long string, syntax highlighting stops working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, syntax-highlighting

This is not in any way related to this issue

[image: broken syntax highlight example]

The IDE I am using is Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

For demonstration purposes, the long string is a base64 encoded image 44,517 characters long (too large to paste here in a code block so I have it up on pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/CHUH9zjv))

The reason why I am embedding the image directly into the class is out of laziness. I do not wish to add all the images as resources for every project I wish to use this class inside, and since `Resources` loads the image from a base64 encoded version anyway, this is functionally no different but has the advantage of making the class a drop-in object (embedded, not compiled as an extra dll).

CodeSense continues to work, but as you can imagine lack of syntax highlighting, makes me feel like my dev environment just time-warped backwards 20+ years.

Any suggestions on how to correct this problem AND still embed the images directly into the class. (yes, I know, I want to have my cake AND eat it -- else why have a cake ? )

Comment: Is "this issue" in your first sentence meant to be a link to a different topic?

Comment: *`Resources` loads the image from a base64 encoded version anyway* => I believe it's stored as base64 in the resx XML file, but it's converted to a binary resource at compilation. Besides, you could use a resx file located in the same assembly that declares your class.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - having a resx for the assembly would mean that any time I wanted to use this class, it would require me to add the resources by hand to every project.  This is eliminated by having the object embedded directly in the class. Minimizing distribution chaos by keeping everything as self-contained as possible. (eg, Portable single file executable or as some say 'monolithic' build)

Comment: @Sanuel nope, you add the resources only to *one* project, then use them from other projects, or write a class that encapsulates access to the shared resource. I see no need for resource duplication here. Of course if you only want *one* assemlby in the end that's another story - you'd need something like ILMerge or LibZ.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - adding to another project creates another assembly which as you mentioned would have to be embedded using a merging application which essentially just builds a wrapper around the main file -- a process which has historically adds headaches. Another option is to try and figure out how I can compile this lib as an obj/lib and link it at compile, but if memory serves this too is a painful process now.  Appreciate the response :) ... Just I am looking to keep things compact without external dependency (aside from .NET framework of course) :)

Comment: @Sanuel yeah I think I misunderstood your issue in the first place - you're actually including that cs file in several projects directly, I thought you included that cs file once in a shared assembly until you edited your comment above :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem seems to have been fixed in Visual Studio 2015. I cannot reproduce it there using the code from your pastebin. I was however able to reproduce it in VS2013, so it's not just you.

In the meantime, one workaround that immediately comes to mind is to split the literal into chunks, since highlighting works just fine if the literals are short enough. Even just two 20-kilobyte chunks does the trick in my case. <del>I'm not sure what the magic number is, but it's probably not worth trying to find out.</del>

Scratch that — the magic number is, just as I suspected, 32,768, found through liberal use of copy and paste. This limit is specifically of the total length of a single line of code, including whitespace and punctuation (quotes, parens, etc), so when chunking the string literal make sure each chunk is on its own line. It's fine to concatenate them within a single statement so long as the statement is split across lines.

Comment: going to try this as I believe you are correct.  you wouldn't happen to know what the maximum size is I can chunk it into ?

Comment: @Sanuel Jackson: Wasn't going to find out, but I stumbled upon it with some quick wits and a bit of messing around. Just updated my answer.

Comment: Just tested this, and it works.  Please update your answer to note that the limit includes `"` (quotations) around the string. So technically, the max string length is 32766 with surrounding quotes.

Comment: Update:  The 32,768 character limit includes all characters including tab/space/quotes both before and after the string, except for the `+` character if added to the end of the string. If adding the `+` character before the string, it is also counted towards the limit.

Comment: @Sanuel Jackson: Yeah, that's what I meant by "the total length of a single line of code" initially. It turns out that it's not the length of a string literal at all.

Answer (score 0):

you tried to declare static variable and load it from TXT file? and put the byt value within the TXT file.
or you can split the string within more than variable!

Comment: @SanuelJackson You can put anything into resources.

Comment: @PetSerAl ~ the key is 'I do not wish to add all the images as resources for every project I wish to use this class inside'.  In other words keeping it compact and self-contained and fully natural embedded code for any project I wish to use the class inside with no external dependencies. [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31349096/3504007) resolved the problem and keeps everything contained.